# Error deploying SonarCube on an OpenShift Cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, sonarqube

I have added a SonarQube operator (https://github.com/RedHatGov/sonarqube-operator) in my cluster and when I want to let a Sonar instance out of the operator, the container terminates with the Fail Message:

```
ERROR: [1] bootstrap checks failed
[1]: max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [253832] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
```

The problem lies in the fact that the operator refers to the label;

```
tuned.openshift.io/elasticsearch
```

which leaves me to do the necessary tuning, but there is no Elasticsearch operator or tuning on this pristine cluster.

I have created a tuning for Sonar but for whatever reason the thing does not want to be pulled. It currently looks like this:

```
apiVersion: tuned.openshift.io/v1
kind: Tuned
metadata:
  name: sonarqube
  namespace: openshift-cluster-node-tuning-operator
spec:
  profile:
  - data: |
      [main]
      summary=A custom OpenShift SonarQube profile
      include=openshift-control-plane
      [sysctl]
      vm.max_map_count=262144
    name: openshift-sonarqube
  recommend:
  - match:
    - label: tuned.openshift.io/sonarqube
      match:
      - label: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
      - label: node-role.kubernetes.io/infra
      type: pod
    priority: 10
    profile: openshift-sonarqube
```

and on the deployment I give the label;

```
tuned.openshift.io/sonarqube
```

But for whatever reason it is not pulled and I still get the above error message. Does anyone have an idea, and/or are these necessary steps? I followed the documentation > (https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/openshift_container_platform/4.8/html/scalability_and_performance/using-node-tuning-operator) and it didn't work with the customized example. I set the match in match again, but that didn't work either.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
oc create -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: tuned.openshift.io/v1
kind: Tuned
metadata:
  name: openshift-elasticsearch
  namespace: openshift-cluster-node-tuning-operator
spec:
  profile:
  - data: |
      [main]
      summary=Optimize systems running ES on OpenShift nodes
      include=openshift-node
      [sysctl]
      vm.max_map_count=262144
    name: openshift-elasticsearch
  recommend:
  - match:
    - label: tuned.openshift.io/elasticsearch
      type: pod
    priority: 20
    profile: openshift-elasticsearch
EOF
```

(Got it from: https://github.com/openshift/cluster-node-tuning-operator/blob/master/examples/elasticsearch.yaml)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).